# Sorting & Extracting Data On Excel Through a Drop Down List

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, excel-formula

I am trying to develop a database interface on Excel for my colleagues which will allow them to sort through metrics of our Facebook videos.

The database looks like this:

[image: Database example]

To date they have been using the custom sort feature on excel each time they want to find the best video per specified criteria e.g views, shares, or comments

In order to simplify the process, I thought of building a small interface on a separate excel tab which would allow the same custom sorting features but through the use of a drop down list.

e.g Let's say they would like to sort the best performing videos by user engagement:

[image: Drop down sort example]

This would then return the top 5 videos with the highest engagement.

Custom sort allows multiple sorts on excel So I was wondering if I could go a step further and replicate this feature through multiple drop down lists?

I hope that I was clear enough with my questioning and my snapshot examples. I look forward to hearing your responses.

Many thanks!

Comment: Is the question "Can it be done?" in which case the answer is yes, if you are asking how, your best bet is to post what you have done so far and where you are getting errors and then we can help from there.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your response. Please forgive me if my question was not clear enough. Indeed, the question is can it be done? and thereafter could any one guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Should probably look up a few things, look up 'how to fire macro on cell change', that will take care of your dropdown change. Look at search a range for a value and returning the column, that will give you which column to filter by for use in something like `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$60").AutoFilter Field:=2`. Then look up the VBA for sorting values highest to lowest.